# Using uniqueness of characteristic function.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

Use the uniqueness of characteristic functions to pove that $\{X_{i}\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ are independent and identically distributed with "Cauchy Law," $S_{n}=X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n}.$ Then $\frac{S_{n}}{n}\rightarrow 0$ in distribution, when $n$ goes to infinity.

I was thinking in use,evidently the uniqueness of characterístic function. So, $\frac{S_{n}}{n}$ has the same distribution, for example, as $X_{1}.$ Then both random variables has the same distribution. But, ¿how can I do to reach to the goal?

I can't see why $\frac{S_{n}}{n}$ convergence in distribution.

Any kind of idea will be thanked in advance.

Comment: In fact, the statement should be $\frac{S_n}{n}$ converge in distribution to a Cauchy Law of same parameters than $X_i$.

Comment: Let r.v.'s $\xi_n$ to have charasteristic functions $\psi_n(t)$ and r.v. $\xi$ to have a charasteristic function $\phi(t)$.

Then $\psi_n(t) \rightarrow \phi(t)$ for every $t$ iff $\xi_n \rightarrow \xi$ in distribution.

Therefore you need to count a charasteristic function of $\frac{S_n}{n}$ and prove its convergence to the charasteristic function of the distribution placed in zero point.

Comment: Thanks for answer @DenisKorzhenkov. But I still cannot see why $\frac{S_{n}}{n}$ convergence to 0, because both $S_{n}/n$ and $X_{1}$ have the same characteristic function and then, the same distribution. So the convergence between them is hold for every value. In particular, when we evaluate in 0. But the distribution in 0 is equal to 1/2, and 1 if we evaluate the characteristic function.

Comment: @Suiz96 sorry, I didn't get it. You are right, this ratio doesn't converge to 0. But, e.g., $S_n / n^2$ does. Are you sure your task is correct?